# XDomainRequest onload not running

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a cross-domain request that works fine with $.getJSON. But in IE I'm getting a pesky **Access is Denied** error. Maybe I'm not understanding the onload paramter or XDR but when I add in parameters nothing happens just hangs no errors or nothing. Here is the code:

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "http://somedomain.com?callback=?");
xdr.onload = function() {
  $.extend($.CSSService.sessionData,{"call_type":"create"});
  $.extend($.CSSService.sessionData,data);
  $.CSSService.sessionData.typing = false;
  timeoutTimer = setTimeout(PollServer,100);
  if(Callback) setTimeout(Callback,500);
};
xdr.send();
```

Here is the perfectly working JSON call in every other browser.

```
$.getJSON("http://somedomain.com?callback=?",$.extend($.CSSService.sessionData,        {"call_type":"create"}),function(data){
  $.extend($.CSSService.sessionData,data);
  $.CSSService.sessionData.typing = false;
  timeoutTimer = setTimeout(PollServer,100);
  if(Callback) setTimeout(Callback,500);      
}
});
```

I've been stumped on this for hours. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. Code samples are greatly appreciated as my JSON and jQuery aren't up to par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second snippet specifies a callback parameter, so `$.getJSON` actually uses JSONP, which is fine cross-domain.

You first snippet attempts to use CORS. Since the request is getting denied, I assume the remote server hasn't implemented CORS or just doesn't want to allow your domain.

The second snippet should work in all browsers, including IE8.

Comment: Thanks for replying @JasonP I'm kind of confused by your comment. The second snippet does not work in IE, any version. If the code looks right can the remote server block cross domain requests? That doesn't make sense to me cause their API clearly states they allow it, thoroughly confused here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: JSONP should be supported by all browsers, including IE. If it isn't, maybe there is an issue elsewhere. Have you checked your javascript error console and the network tab of the browser tools?

Comment: In IE I get a **Access is Denied** error anytime I try to access one of the objects returned from the JSON string.

Comment: _"When I try to access one of the objects returned from the JSON string"_ -- So it is making it to the callback, but you can't access the returned data?

Comment: Exactly. I can't return any of the data. So when I try to access any object returned from the callback I get an **Access is denied**